# How to fix this ` error TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'HTMLLIElement' `

Tags: typescript-typings

I want to ensure a list of exclusively `<li/>` will be passed to a component such that they will be displayed inside a `<ul>` element as rendered by the said component.

Here is my code:

```
  const menuItems: HTMLLIElement[] = [
    <li>Item 1</li>,
    <li>Item 2</li>,
    <li>Item 3</li>,
  ];
```

For each line of `<li>` inside the array, I get this error:

```
 error TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'HTMLLIElement'.
```

I have tried an alternative way to create an array of `li` element

```
  const menuItems = [
    React.createElement(HTMLLIElement, {value: 'Item 1' }),
    React.createElement(HTMLLIElement, {value: 'Item 2' }),
    React.createElement(HTMLLIElement, {value: 'Item 3' }),
  ]
```

but it just gave a different error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ new (): HTMLLIElement; prototype: HTMLLIElement; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | FunctionComponent<{ value: string; }> | ComponentClass<{ value: string; }, any>'.
  Type '{ new (): HTMLLIElement; prototype: HTMLLIElement; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{ value: string; }, any>'.
    Type 'HTMLLIElement' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<{ value: string; }, any, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.
```

How can I resolve this isse?

Comment: Do you have to have this typing `: HTMLLIElement[]`? You can change it into `: Element[]` and problem should disappear. or event `const menuItems = [...` TS will know that is `Element[]`

Comment: Your comment is akin to "If I stop breathing and die, all my life problem will go away" . Please, please note I mentioned in the question "I want to ensure a list of exclusively <li/> ...". I want the type system to help me to achieve this guarantee.

Comment: That wasn't my point, sorry for oversimplification.

Comment: I have other idea, Please try `const menuItems: HTMLLIElement[] = [` instead of `const menuItems = [ ...] as HTMLLIElement[]`